# Logging in another process

Tags: c#, performance, logging, client-server, ipc

I have a IIS server. That server gets web requests and does some computation for multiple clients. Within these computations, there are log entries made. These log entries work with a flag so that they can be shut down. Shutting the log entries off completely gets me a very high performance boost. Or in other words, logging takes a lot of time but it is necessary so just shutting it off is not an option.

My idea is that I want to push the log entries to another process so maybe let the computation of the server run quickly on demand and have the log be written by another process, giving it some leverage to write it when less resources are needed.

First off, a few questions about the idea itelf. My Idea is as  follows:

- Send the log string from the server to another process
- Save the log string to a queue in the log process
- Have the log process periodically, in another thread, check the queue for entries, writing to file if there is something to write and then sleep
- Limiting access to the queue via mutex to avoid conflicts

So the question to begin with is, can this even enhance the overall performance the clients experience or will it just create an overhead worsening the problem?

**Now, lets get more specific.**

I use c# IpcChannel Class for my first implementation of this system. [According to the example on the microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). I have not yet made a measurement on whether or not the implementation is quicker, because there are still some open questions.

I implemented the IpcClient in my IIS Server. I start the IpcServer in another process. Then I start a IIS Client. So, the three processes here are:

- IpcServer
- IIS Server, implementing IpcClient
- IIS Client Application

The communication, as I understand it, goes as follows:

- User calls some function on IIS Client
- IIS Client sends webrequest to IIS Server
- IIS Server runs computation and logs, calling the IpcClient method
- The IpcClient method is sent to the IpcServer process
- The IpcServer process writes the log stirng to file

**Now for the tricky part**

I have built a debug log into the IpcChannel, meaning that it writes a line of text into a log every time it checks the queue for strings to be written into the actual log. After stopping the IpcServer process, this continues. I assumed that this would interrupt the loop but somehow all of this keeps going until I shut down the IIS Server process. This is very confusing to me. Without the IpcServer, assuming the log is actually done by the IpcServer proecss, I would assume that the debug log stops, but it does not. Any Idea on why this is?

Here is the loop that is my RemoteObject according to the microsoft example provided above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace RemoteProcedureCall
{
    public class RemoteObject : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        const int MessageBuffer = 10;
        Queue<string> Messages = new Queue<string>();
        const string FilePath = "Test_Log.txt";
        const string DebugLogFilePath = "DebugLog.txt";
        Mutex QueueMutex = new Mutex(false, nameof(QueueMutex));
        private int callCount = 0;
        Thread WriterTask;

        public int GetCount()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetCount has been called.");
            callCount++;
            return (callCount);
        }

        #region Shortcuts

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls <see cref="File.AppendAllText(string, string)"/> using <see cref="FilePath"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        private void WriteLine(string text) => File.AppendAllText(FilePath, $"{text}{Environment.NewLine}");

        /// <summary>
        /// <see cref="WriteLine(string)"/> debug version
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        private void DebugConsole(string text) => File.AppendAllText(DebugLogFilePath, $"{text}{Environment.NewLine}");

        private void DequeueAndWriteMessage()
        {
            QueueMutex.WaitOne();
            if (Messages.Count != 0)
                WriteLine(Messages.Dequeue());
            QueueMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }

        private void Flush()
        {
            DebugConsole($"------------------------------!!Flushing!!------------------------------");
            while (Messages.Count != 0)
                DequeueAndWriteMessage();
        }

        #endregion Shortcuts

        private void PrintMessagesTask()
        {
            DebugConsole($"Starting PrintMessagetast");
            try {
                while (true) {
                    DebugConsole($"Dequeue and write message in secondary thread");
                    DequeueAndWriteMessage();
                    if (Messages.Count < MessageBuffer) {
                        Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        DebugConsole("Thread.Sleep(5000);");
                    }
                    else {
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                        DebugConsole("Thread.Sleep(10);");
                    }
                }
            }
            finally {
                Flush();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a Message to the <see cref="Messages"/> for them to later be posted to log file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        public void AddMessage(string text)
        {
            DebugConsole($"Enqueue Message");
            QueueMutex.WaitOne();

            Messages.Enqueue($"Enqueueing Message Nr. {GetCount()}:");
            Messages.Enqueue(text);

            QueueMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }

        public void StartWriterThread()
        {
            DebugConsole($"Starting second thread");
            ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(PrintMessagesTask);
            WriterTask = new Thread(threadStart);
            WriterTask.Start();
            DebugConsole($"Started second thread");
        }

        public void AbortWriterThread()
        {
            WriterTask.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

The IIS Server calls "StartWriterThread()" and then loops some "AddMessage" calls.

Comment: _"Logging takes a lot of time but it is necessary so just shutting it off is not an option"_ it looks like you can optimize your logging, for example by keeping the file open rather than calling File.AppendAllText for every message, and / or batching messages to reduce the number of writes, or using a logging framework that is optimised for this kind of work. _"Can this even enhance the overall performance the clients experience or will it just create an overhead worsening the problem"_ - the answer to that is "it depends". You need to investigate **why** there is performance degredation.

Comment: The logging in my example uses File.AppendAllText as a quick and dirty way to apply the given mode with the IpcChannels. Its just a simple example so that I dont have to worry about thread safe writing too much, because even though I used a mutex, somehow trying to write multiple times makes the application crash.

Thats besides the point though. The performance problem is caused by the general system in how server and client communicate. But the system itself is already too big to change. So I was trying to reduce the time the application stops for logging and push it to another process.

Comment: You don't need to roll your own stuff. Windows has already all the logging infrastructure you need: ETW https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2012/07/09/introduction-tutorial-logging-etw-events-in-c-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource/

Comment: Can you include a MVCE? It is the server that execute the methods of the remote object.

Answer (score 1):

first I would suggest to track down in detail what code-parts cause which delay. (e.g by System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch, intrinsic in code)

it is not a good idea to add more complexity to compensate for "assumed issues".

after finding dominant regions in the code, optimization is much more easy.

optimization ideas:

- avoid complex c# "managed" functions for high-performance functions.
- There are several types/ways to access/generate (log) files. it is essential to choose the right one, according to case
- it is more efficient to access a (log) file, instead of spawning multi threads or using stacks
- pre-calc/estimate the max.frequency required for logging
- find all blocking / non-Async parts in code and measure the delay
- file accesses are limited physically. pre-calc your physical bottelneck. (e.g. for SSD etc)
- **let windows decide** when real physical access happens. never try to flush, clear cache etc.
- use timeout handling to detect + avoid lagging/interleaving effects
- instead of implementing a complex solution to allow "multiple threads to write to single file" - an option is to generate a **log-file/folder-hierarchy** instead, and filter/combine **only** when **viewing/processing** = much more cleaner concept with high performance
- hint: if you use log file access in various locations in your code, you (could) have "multi thread access" already (without knowing)
- instead of using multiple apps, combine them in one. so there is no need to use any kind of IPC

I use all this in a server side .NET-app to handle websockets(browser)+mqtt(IoT) for a multi-client setup.

websocket stress-test is generating >>200Hz for bi-directional communication with data file generation/logging. (i5 server cpu, abyss + .NET apps)

BTW:

if the general app/concept is "too big to change" you need to accept the resulting (bad) performance

soft+hardware NEVER gets better by adding something (overhead) to compensate for a weak concept

Answer (score 0):

It would be much faster to spawn a thread utilizing a ConcurrentBag object and calling the Add() method, instead of Console.WriteLine() and then log the events to a file as they arrive within that thread, write the text and delete from concurrent bag.

If live monitoring is required, create a separate program using the FileSystemWatcher class that will display the live changes to the file.

Comment: I am not looking for a solution that would simply change the tool used to log or store strings. I am looking for an explanation about the pros and cons of sending the strings to another process and also to explain the behaviour of the IpcChannel implementation